# Vectorizing loop in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, vector, vectorization

Is there a way to vectorize the following loop in MATLAB?

```
for j = 1:length(cursor_bin)
    cursor_bin(j) = mean(cursor(bin == j));
end
```

`cursor_bin`, `cursor`, and `bin` are all vectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) does just that:

```
cursor_bin = accumarray(bin(:), cursor(:), [], @mean);
```

Answer (score 4):

`bsxfun` approach for non-zero `cursor` arrays -

```
t1 = bsxfun(@eq,bin(:),1:numel(cursor_bin))
t2 = bsxfun(@times,t1,cursor(:))
t2(t2==0)=NaN
cursor_bin = nanmean(t2)
```

Comment: I was just updating my question with that... +1

Comment: Maybe use `bin(:)` instead of `bin` to make sure it's a column? And same for `cursor`: `cursor(:).'`

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks!! Almost missed that one!

Comment: @LuisMendo and Divakar, thanks to both of you. I've done MATLAB for a long time but am just starting to learn how much faster vectorizing can be!

Comment: @vman049 Good luck with that and explore more about `bsxfun` [here](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)